# Backpropagation implementation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I have to implement backpropagation from scratch on a dataset and i struggle to find why i always encounter a bug where the matrix multiplication is not possible. For now i just loaded my data from a dataset, split it into training and testing sets, implemented sigmoid and mean squared error and also forward propagation:

```
def split_data(data, train_ratio=0.8):
    split_index = int(train_ratio * len(data))
    training_set = data[:split_index]
    training_set = [[float(element) if element else float('nan') for element in row] for row in training_set]
    training_set = [list(filter(lambda x: not np.isnan(x), row)) for row in training_set]

    testing_set = data[split_index:]
    testing_set = [[float(element) if element else float('nan') for element in row] for row in testing_set]
    testing_set = [list(filter(lambda x: not np.isnan(x), row)) for row in testing_set]

    print("Training set: ", training_set)
    print("Testing set: ", testing_set)
    return training_set, testing_set


# Ex 2. Initialize parameters
def initialize_biases(hidden_neurons_per_layers, output_size):
    biases = []

    # Hidden layers biases
    hidden_biases = [np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(1, neurons)) for neurons in hidden_neurons_per_layers]
    biases.extend(hidden_biases)

    # Output layer bias
    output_biases = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(1, output_size))
    biases.append(output_biases)
    print("Biases\n", biases)
    return biases


def initialize_weights(input_size, hidden_neurons_per_layer, output_size):
    np.random.seed(42)
    weights = []

    weights.append(np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(hidden_neurons_per_layer[0], input_size)))

    for i in range(1, len(hidden_neurons_per_layer)):
        weights.append(
            np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(hidden_neurons_per_layer[i], hidden_neurons_per_layer[i - 1])))

    weights.append(np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(output_size, hidden_neurons_per_layer[-1])))

    return weights

# Ex3 Activation function and its derivative, mean squared error
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))


def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))


def mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_true):
    return (1 / 2) * np.mean((y_pred - y_true) ** 2)


# Ex4 forward propagation
def compute_output(input, weight, bias):
    if not isinstance(weight, np.ndarray):
        weight = np.array([[weight]])  # Convert scalar to 2D array

    input_copy = input.copy().reshape(-1, 1)
    print("WEIGHT: ", weight)
    print("INPUT: ", input_copy)
    matrix = np.matmul(weight, input_copy.T) + bias  # Transpose input_copy
    result_matrix = np.vectorize(sigmoid)(matrix)
    return result_matrix


def evaluate(input, layers, biases):
    output = []
    input_copy = input.copy()
    for i in range(len(layers)):
        bias = get_bias_matrix(biases[i])
        output = compute_output(input_copy, layers[i], bias)
        input_copy = output
    return output

def evaluate2(input, layers, biases):
    output = []
    input_copy = input.copy()
    An = [input_copy]

    for i in range(len(layers)):
        bias = get_bias_matrix(biases[i])
        output = compute_output(input_copy, layers[i], bias)
        input_copy = output
        An.append(output)

    return output, An

def get_input_matrix(row):
    input_data = row[:-1]
    input_matrix = np.array(input_data).reshape(-1, 1)
    return input_matrix


def get_output_matrix(row, layers, biases):
    input_matrix = get_input_matrix(row)
    output = evaluate2(input_matrix, layers, biases)[0]
    return output


def get_bias_matrix(row):
    input_matrix = np.array(row).reshape(-1, 1)
    return input_matrix




def backprop(biases, weights, layers, x, y):
    Bns = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in biases]
    Wns = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in weights]

    Zn = []
    An = [x]
    a = 0
    count = 0

    # Forward pass ?
    for b, w in zip(biases, weights):
        count += 1
        print("Iteration: ", count)
        print("W: ", w)
        if len(Zn) == 0:
            print("VALOARE X: ", x)
        print("VALOARE a: ", a)
        print("BIASES b: ", b)
        z = np.dot(w, a) + b if Zn else np.dot(w, x) + b
        a = sigmoid(z)
        Zn.append(z)
        An.append(a)

    H = len(layers) - 2

    for L in range(H, -1, -1):
        delta = sigmoid_derivative(Zn[L]) * (weights[L + 1].T @ delta) if L != len(layers) - 2 else (An[L] - y) * sigmoid_derivative(Zn[L])
        Bns[L] = delta
        Wns[L] = An[L - 1] @ delta.T if L != 0 else x @ delta.T


    return Bns, Wns



def evaluate_and_train(training_set, layers, weights, biases, alpha, max_epochs):
    for epoch in range(max_epochs):
        for entry in training_set:
            x = get_input_matrix(entry)
            y = get_output_matrix(entry, layers, biases)
            Bns, Wns = backprop(biases, weights, layers, x, y)

            # Update weights and biases using gradient descent
            biases = [b - alpha * nb for b, nb in zip(biases, Bns)]
            weights = [w - alpha * nw for w, nw in zip(weights, Wns)]

            total_error = 0
            for entry in training_set:
                x = get_input_matrix(entry)
                y_true = get_output_matrix(entry)
                y_pred = evaluate(x, layers, biases)[0]
                total_error += mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_true)

    return weights, biases
```

Tried to implement backpropagation, but i have bugs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.